# Navfn vs Smac Planner

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Was just trying out the new smac planner in foxy and I saw some unexpected behavior.

It looks like smac planner is ignoring costs when obstacles are too small.
Navfn on the other side doesn't show this behavior.

**Navfn:**

[image: navfn gif]

**Smac:**

[image: smac gif]

Costmap looks fine, and on the smac planner param side I think they seem reasonable.
But I am not sure if there is a bug or misconfiguration on my side.

```
planner_server:
  ros__parameters:
    planner_plugins: ["GridBased"]
    use_sim_time: True

    # smac_planner/SmacPlanner is replaced with nav2_navfn_planner/NavfnPlanner, params are from smac, but navfn works better right now
    GridBased:
      plugin: "nav2_navfn_planner/NavfnPlanner"
      tolerance: 0.5                    # tolerance for planning if unable to reach exact pose, in meters, for 2D node
      downsample_costmap: false         # whether or not to downsample the map
      downsampling_factor: 1            # multiplier for the resolution of the costmap layer (e.g. 2 on a 5cm costmap would be 10cm)
      allow_unknown: false              # allow traveling in unknown space
      max_iterations: -1                # maximum total iterations to search for before failing
      max_on_approach_iterations: 1000  # maximum number of iterations to attempt to reach goal once in tolerance, 2D only
      max_planning_time: 2.0            # max time in s for planner to plan, smooth, and upsample. Will scale maximum smoothing and upsampling times based on remaining time after planning.
      smooth_path: false                # Whether to smooth searched path
      motion_model_for_search: "DUBIN"  # 2D Moore, Von Neumann; SE2 Dubin, Redds-Shepp
      angle_quantization_bins: 72       # For SE2 node: Number of angle bins for search, must be 1 for 2D node (no angle search)
      minimum_turning_radius: 0.20      # For SE2 node & smoother: minimum turning radius in m of path / vehicle
      reverse_penalty: 2.1              # For Reeds-Shepp model: penalty to apply if motion is reversing, must be => 1
      change_penalty: 0.20              # For SE2 node: penalty to apply if motion is changing directions, must be >= 0
      non_straight_penalty: 1.05        # For SE2 node: penalty to apply if motion is non-straight, must be => 1
      cost_penalty: 1.3                 # For SE2 node: penalty to apply to higher cost zones

      smoother:
        smoother:
          w_curve: 30.0                 # weight to minimize curvature of path
          w_dist: 0.0                   # weight to bind path to original as optional replacement for cost weight
          w_smooth: 30000.0             # weight to maximize smoothness of path
          w_cost: 0.025                 # weight to steer robot away from collision and cost
          cost_scaling_factor: 10.0     # this should match the inflation layer's parameter

        # I do not recommend users mess with this unless they're doing production tuning
        optimizer:
          max_time: 0.10                # maximum compute time for smoother
          max_iterations: 500           # max iterations of smoother
          debug_optimizer: false        # print debug info
          gradient_tol: 1.0e-10
          fn_tol: 1.0e-20
          param_tol: 1.0e-15
          advanced:
            min_line_search_step_size: 1.0e-20
            max_num_line_search_step_size_iterations: 50
            line_search_sufficient_function_decrease: 1.0e-20
            max_num_line_search_direction_restarts: 10
            max_line_search_step_expansion: 50
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/372400/navfn-vs-smac-planner/) by [madmax](https://answers.ros.org/users/1492/madmax/) on ROS Answers with karma: 496 on 2021-02-22

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2021-02-23**:
Please file a ticket on Nav2 about this with this info and reproduction examples - I haven't seen this behavior before and we should look into it. It's probably an easy fix, but we just need to understand fully what the issue is first.

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2021-02-23**:
I'd be curious to know if you used Nav2 main branch if you saw these issues. This looks awfully similar to a ticket that resulted in a patch that will be in Galactic and newer https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/pull/2090 on the same behavior with NavFn (ABI incompatiable with Foxy, but I'd be open to a PR to make a different fix for Foxy to resolve this behavior) that was the results of current / clearing operations, not the algorithms themselves.

**Comment by [madmax](https://answers.ros.org/users/1492/madmax/) on 2021-02-26**:
I used foxy debs. Issue is opened [here.](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/issues/2207)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We're going to take this to the issue tracker in Nav2.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2021-02-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0